# Why isn't Wireguard available on F-Droid?

Tags: vpn, f-droid

Lots of sites speak of Wireguard being available on F-Droid but I noticed it's no longer on the site. Why is this? And how can I install it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official Wireguard App is no longer available because the [author insists in packing self-updating functionality that targets a non-F-droid repository](https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroiddata/-/issues/3110). This functionality means that F-Droid can't ensure that the software running that was originally installed with F-Droid, was built by F-Droid. It's no longer repeatable, nor auditable.

This put the author and F-Droid at odds, and the package was de-listed.

As an alternative,

- Use the WG-Tunnel app (available in f-droid), https://github.com/zaneschepke/wgtunnel and it uses the same wireguard-android library under the hood.
- Or, install from Izzy F-Droid repo https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.wireguard.android

Comment: Thank you for pointing us to wgtunnel. It appears to be a well-maintained project. Disappointed that the author chose to take a stand because of his apparent personal disagreements with F-Droid leadership. Going to stick with F-Droid and try wgtunnel.